# Find which revision an export is from

Tags: git

I have a directory with source code. There is a repository with that project, but the directory in question does not have any metadata or any manual report of which version it is based on. How can find which version is it closest to (it may contain some modifications that were never checked in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [eckes'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655234/201725) suggestion I whipped up following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 path-to-export [rev-list-options...]"
    exit 1
fi

alt_work_tree=$1
shift

git rev-list "$@" | {
    min_changes=$(git --work-tree="$alt_work_tree" status --porcelain | wc -l)
    closest_revs=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    lines=0

    while read revision; do
    git checkout -q "$revision"
    n_changes=$(git --work-tree="$alt_work_tree" status --porcelain | wc -l)
    if [ "$n_changes" -lt "$min_changes" ]; then
        min_changes=$n_changes
        closest_revs=$revision
    elif [ "$n_changes" -eq "$min_changes" ]; then
        closest_revs="$closest_revs $revision"
    fi
    lines=$((lines + 1))

    printf "rev: %s n: %s min_changes: %s   \r" "$revision" "$lines" "$min_changes"
    done

    echo
    echo "Number of changes left: $min_changes"
    echo "Possible revisions: $closest_revs"
    echo "Checking out: ${closest_revs%% *}"
    git checkout -q "${closest_revs%% *}"
}
```

For one case I tried it found a revision that matches, for the other case it found something that makes sense and there was no exact match, so I guess it gets the job done.

The script is rather inefficient, because it checks out each revision, which is completely unnecessary. However I couldn't quickly get `git status` to use different index file.

Feel free to use and modify whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You could init a repository in the directory in question.

Then with `git cat-file commit HEAD` you can see the tree object.

Now you can iterate over your commits and try to find the commit with an identical tree-SHA1 sum.

If that's not the case, use `git ls-tree HEAD` and iterate over all commits to find a tree that is as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your history is reasonable short, you could try the following:

- go to your repo
- iterate over the revisions of this repo and set `--work-tree` to the directory where you have the source code
- check which revision has the least differences to the state of your directory

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could abuse `git bisect` for this:

- start the bisecting process using `git bisect bad`
- claim the very first commit in the repo to be `git bisect good`
- now, the bisecting will present you the revisions for bisecting
- for each step, issue a `git status --work-tree=/path/to/your/sources`

  - if you have few differences, claim this revision to be good
  - if you have lots of differences, claim this revision to be bad

Comment: No, bisect would only work if I could tell whether the revision is newer or older than the sources. `git status --work-tree` looks like a useful trick though.